# Refetching a locally deleted file from Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hg-revert

I deleted one of the files that was in my repository *locally* (just at the file system level, not using `hg remove`). I now want to get that file back from the repository to my local directory. When I do `hg status`, it knows that the file is locally deleted, but there are no changes to be commited which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
$ hg revert your-file
```

will restore it.

**Edit:** see http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revert

Comment: Ah yeah. And I see hg `revert --all` does it too, but thats the nuclear button. I used `--all` as I was trying to avoid typing the (in this case really long) file name. Is there a command to re-pull everything from the repository to the local directory, except for changed files. Maybe thats too long a discussion...

Answer (score 11):

The following will revert all deleted files in the current repo:

```
hg status -nd0|xargs -0 hg revert
```

Comment: I will love you forever.

Answer (score 6):

cd to your dir and do "hg revert ." to restore all files or used any appropriate mask like *.java, etc.. This will effect only the current dir (not sure about subdirs).